# Keep TabBar Large Title on swipe swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UIViewController which holds a UITableView and also have a navigation bar with a large title. Whenever I scroll down through the table view, the large title disappears and becomes a small header. How can I maintain the large title (make it static/sticky) when I scroll through.

I added a picture of my screen [before the swipe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QRd9.png), [in the middle of a swipe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUIZ7.png), [and after the swipe.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBwOL.png)

I want to maintain the large title seen in the [before the swipe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QRd9.png) image even after the swipe occurs.

The code I currently have in terms of the navigation bar (for the large header and transparency) is as follows

class OneChallengeViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
let productCellId = "TableViewCell1TableViewCell"
var products = [ProductDto]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()
 
 
 navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
 navigationItem.title = "Challenges"
 navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .default
 navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
 navigationController?.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always



 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title will collapse on scroll as long as the root view is scrollable, i.e. is a scrollView or a view which embeds a `UIScrollView`.

To achieve what you want in the particular case you'd need to add a dummy view ahead of your `tableView` in the view hierarchy.

I've found your question while searching how to achieve the opposite